# How to query any constraint's target list without knowing the constraint type?

Tags: python, 3d, constraints, maya, mel

In Maya, I have a list of constraints gathered by the following code.  I want to iterate the constraints and query the targets for each of them:

```
cons = ls(type='constraint')
for con in cons:
    targets = constraint(query=True, targetList=True)
```

The problem, there is no general `constraint` command for manipulating all constraints. Instead, each constraint has its own unique MEL command associated with it.

Is there any way to query the targets on a constraint without having to type check each constraint and tediously run its respective MEL command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

listConnections on the .target attr

the cleanup in mel:

```
string $cons[] = `ls -type "constraint"`;
for ( $con in $cons ){
    string $targetAttrString = ( $con+ ".target" );
    string $connections[] = `listConnections $targetAttrString`;
    string $connectionsFlattened[] = stringArrayRemoveDuplicates($connections);
    for ( $f in $connectionsFlattened )
        if ( $f != $con )
            print ( $f+ " is a target\n" );
}
```